# Integer Validation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I am trying to use a DBContext to automatically validate my entities and display a message on screen. The get validation errors successfully detects all non-nullable properties of type string as they still have a value of null. My problem arises when I try to validate a property of type int. The value is already set to 0 by default and as it is a foreign key id I need this value to not be 0,but it does not get detected.

```
        //Create a database context over current ObjectContext          
        var databaseContext = new DbContext(this, true);

        //Get Validation Errors
        var errors = databaseContext.GetValidationErrors();

        //Display errors on screen
        if (errors.Any())
        {
            var errorList = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in error.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    errorList.AppendLine(validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            var vm = IoC.Get<ModalConfirmationViewModel>();
            vm.Message = errorList.ToString();

            var wm = IoC.Get<WindowManager>();
            wm.ShowDialog(vm);

            return false;
        }
```

Thoughts?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 9):

You can use Range to validate if a property is within a specific range:

```
 [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "BarIdMustBeGreaterThanZero",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
 int BarId{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making it a nullable int.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? BarId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The properties are automatically set on the entities everytime the edmx is generated. As far as I am aware I can't manually set them.